# How to use fakerjs in Cypress

Tags: cypress, ui-testing, faker

I am trying to use fakerjs in my cypress tests to randomly generate fake data for my forms. I have tried exporting it in `support/index.js` which did not work.

Is there any standard way to add fakerjs to all cypress specs instead of adding it in every spec file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First off, what's wrong with importing it in every spec?

That being said, you can do this:

cypress/support/index.js:

```js
cy.faker = require('faker');
```

your specs:

```js
it(`test`, () => {
    const words = cy.faker.lorem.words();
});
```

Comment: that's not working, when we call we calll cy.faker it is losing reference to existing selector, can we make it as utility, like we have lodash(Cypress._), moment.(Cypress.moment).etc

Comment: Not sure what "it is losing reference to existing selector" means.

Comment: when I try to use faker like cy.get('#myinput').type(cy.faker.firstName()), it gives me an error that cy is not referring valid input to type

Comment: that has nothing to do with `cy.faker` but rather with `cy.type`. Solve the `cy.type` error (likely because the `cy.get()` didn't find an actionable element), and it'll work.

Comment: cy.type() is working if I have simple text cy.get('#myinput').type('abc'), but it is failing with above error if I use cy.faker.firstName(), anyway, I am able to achieve this without cy. prefix, something like const faker = require('faker') and in my actual statement cy.get('#myinput').type(faker.firstName()). THANKS for the clue.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. Btw, `faker.firstName()` shouldn't work - the API is `faker.name.firstName()` (but maybe you're not on latest version).

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and found very simple. Steps are mentioned below,

1- require faker

```
const faker = require("faker");
```

2- Use where you want like this

```
var firstName = faker.Name.findName(); // Variable declaration
cy.get("#firstName").type(firstName); // Use in locator
```

I hope it would help :)

Answer (score 0):

in Cypress version 13, i'm using `@fakerjs/faker` in two ways.

---

**1. Declare as cypress custom commands**

```
//-- support/command.js

Cypress.Commands.add('faker', () => {
    const { faker } = require('@faker-js/faker');
    return faker;
});

//-- sample usage:

it('passes', () => {
  cy.faker().then((faker) => {
    console.log(faker.person.fullName());
  });
});
```

**2. Use it in js fixtures**

```
//-- fixtures/user.js

const { faker } = require('@faker-js/faker');
module.exports = {
  fullName: faker.person.fullName(),
  phoneNumber: faker.phone.number(),
}

//-- sample usage:

it('passes', () => {
    const user = require('../fixtures/user');
    console.log(user);
});
```

However, by calling the js fixtures with `cy.fixture('user').then()` wont work in this case.

Answer (score -1):

For reference javascript :-
[Https://zetcode.com/javascript/fakerjs/](https://zetcode.com/javascript/fakerjs/)

You can use these in cypress:

```
npm i faker

const faker = require("faker"); 

let username = faker.name.findName()
let email = faker.internet.email()
let password = faker.internet.password()
```

Use all these in single specs file.

Comment: Take a look at the following link to write a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer